# how to solve Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net, initialization, selectcommand

I have a class which I have written all my methods there.
then I have my firstpage of web application which I have some codes there.
I face this

- $exception  {"Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized."}   System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

in the line :

```
sda.Fill(dsUsers.tblMembers);
```

here is my code so I hope u can help me:

```
namespace MosquesNetwork
{
public class cUsers2
{
    SqlConnection scn;
    SqlDataAdapter sda;
    SqlCommandBuilder scb;
    SqlCommand SqlStr;


    public cUsers2()
    {
        SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MosquesDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);


    }

public bool CheckUserName(string UserName)
    {
        DsUsers2 dsUsers=new DsUsers2();
         bool Success;
        string SqlStr="select * from tblUsers where Username='"+UserName+"' ";
        sda.SelectCommand=new SqlCommand(SqlStr, scn);
        sda.Fill(dsUsers.tblMembers);
        sda.Fill(dsUsers.tblMembers);
        Success=dsUsers.tblMembers.Rows.Count>0;
        return Success;
    }
```

then I have this code while the login button is pressed in webform:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtuser.Text.Trim().Length>0 && txtpass.Value.Length>0 )
        {  
            cUsers2 cUsers=new cUsers2();
            DsUsers2 dsUser=new DsUsers2();
            bool Success;
            if (txtuser.Text.Trim()=="admin")
            {
                Success=cUsers.CheckAdminPass(txtuser.Text.Trim(),txtpass.Value.Trim());  
                if (Success)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
                }
            }

            dsUser=cUsers.Checkpassword(txtuser.Text.Trim(), txtpass.Value.Trim(),out Success);
            if(Success)
            {
                Session["ID"]=dsUser.tblMembers.Rows[0][dsUser.tblMembers.IDUserColumn].ToString();
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("frmProfile.aspx");

            }
            else lblerror.Text="invalid username & password";

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your connection was not open anywhere?

Comment: i used .open() also but it says no connection. I think connectionstring is false. how can i know the right connectionstring?

Comment: try to connect to a datasource through visual studio and copy the generated connection string. On the menu, Click on Data->New Data Source

Answer (score 3):

Look at your constructor:

```
SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection(...);
```

That's declaring a *separate* `scn` local variable, so the `scn` *instance* variable is staying as null. If you just change it to:

```
scn = new SqlConnection(...);
```

that may well fix the immediate problem. It's not a nice design in my view - I'd prefer to create the `SqlConnection` in a `using` block where you actually need it - but that's what's going wrong for now...

Comment: Jon Skeet: then it says :     A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

Comment: Most probably your connection string is invalid. Put the exact values you have in the connection string in Sql Management studio and verify that you can connect to the database

Comment: where in sql I can add the string to sql for verfiying ?

Answer (score 0):

I got also this problem. after search the problem found that the object of connection that i have provide SqlDataAdapter is not Initialize so the connection passed as null

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try To Fetch The Value Like this...
protected void Search_Emp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlDataAdapter ad;
    con = new SqlConnection(); //making instance of SqlConnection

    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString; //Invoking Connection String

    con.Open(); //Opening Connection

    if (Ddl_Emp_Search.SelectedItem.Text == "Date Of Joining")
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Emp_Name,Contact_No,City,Emp_Desig,Place_Code from emp_registration where Emp_Doj=@Emp_Doj",con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Emp_Doj", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    }
    else if (Ddl_Emp_Search.SelectedItem.Text == "Name")
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Emp_Name,Place_Code,Emp_Code,Emp_Desig from emp_registration where Emp_Name=@Emp_Name", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Emp_Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    }
    else if (Ddl_Emp_Search.SelectedItem.Text == "Employee Code")
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Emp_Name,Contact_No,City,Emp_Desig,Place_Code from emp_registration where Emp_Code=@Emp_Code", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Emp_Code", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    }
    else if (Ddl_Emp_Search.SelectedItem.Text == "City")
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Emp_Name,Contact_No,City,Emp_Desig,Place_Code from emp_registration where City=@City", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("There is Something Worng....");
    }

    ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); // Here IS THE PROBLEM WHEN YOU DOES'NT PASS CMD (Command instance) to the Data Adapter then there is a problem of ( Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized)

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ad.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You may want to add some comments when posting an answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Try to give a short explanation before the piece of code, so that other users can quickly see what you are achieving.

Answer (score 0):

Vishal Sir, If You are Getting that Problem then Be sure whether you are passing the 'cmd' to the SQL DATA ADAPTER.
for eg:

```
ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```